# How to refer a variable based on substring match result

Tags: r

I wanted to add value label to a variable in the data frame. However, the variable name is based on substring match result. For example, I tried to look for a variable whose name include string “Gender", so I used the code

```
mn<-grep("Gender",names(data),value=TRUE)
```

to locate the variable.

Then I wanted to add value label for that variable, I tried:

```
data$mn<-factor(data$mn,levels=c(2,3),labels=c("Male","Female"))
```

but it did not work. Could anybody help me to fix the problem? Many thanks

Comment: Try `data[,mn] <- lapply(data[,mn], function(x) factor(x, levels=2:3, labels=c('Male', 'Female'))`

Comment: Can you give an example of the data before and after the desired transformation?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) should help you in making reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are multiple variables that match with 'Gender' in the names, we can loop it with `lapply`.

```
 data[,mn] <- lapply(data[,mn], function(x)
             factor(x, levels=2:3, labels=c('Male', 'Female'))
```

If the 'mn' has a length of 1 i.e. only a single column is matched, we don't need a loop (as showed in the comments by @Angela Ju)

```
 data[,mn] <- factor(data[,mn],levels=c(2,3),labels=c("Male","Female"))
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your method, but the result showed it labeled all values as males, no females, and there is a warning message Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , mn, value = list(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  :
  provided 516 variables to replace 1 variables

Comment: @AngelaJu It is better you update your post with an example dataset using `dput` i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(yourdataset)))` and the expected output based on that.  I was coding it based on just your description.  I would suggest 10 rows, 5 column examples

Comment: Hi, I found this code works data[,mn]<-factor(data[,mn],levels=c(2,3),labels=c("Male","Female"))

Comment: @AngelJu Yes, it should work for a single column i.e. if there is a single element in 'mn'.